# What does data.norm() < 1000 do in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, linear-algebra, pytorch, tensor

I am following the PyTorch tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html).
It says that

```
x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)

y = x * 2
while y.data.norm() < 1000:
    y = y * 2

print(y)

Out:    
tensor([-590.4467,   97.6760,  921.0221])
```

Could someone explain what data.norm() does here?
When I change `.randn` to `.ones` its output is  `tensor([ 1024.,  1024.,  1024.])`.

Comment: I don’t know PyTorch but after some searching I think that the norm() method could be related to [the mathematical norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). I don’t know if this is even the same method but I also found a PyTorch doc with a norm() method [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.norm).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's simply the L2 norm (a.k.a Euclidean norm) of the tensor. Below is a reproducible illustration:

```
In [15]: x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)

In [16]: y = x * 2

In [17]: y.data
Out[17]: tensor([-1.2510, -0.6302,  1.2898])

In [18]: y.data.norm()
Out[18]: tensor(1.9041)

# computing the norm using elementary operations
In [19]: torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(y, 2)))
Out[19]: tensor(1.9041)
```

**Explanation**: First, it takes a square of every element in the input tensor `x`, then it sums them together, and finally it takes a square root of the resulting sum. All in all, these operations compute the so-called **[L2 or Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm)**.

Comment: Essentially, it is trying to get a vector of magnitude < 1000 (the L2 norm is can compute Euclidean distance for vectors)

Answer (score 6):

Building on what @kmario23 says, the code multiplies the elements of a vector by 2 until the Euclidean magnitude (distance from origin) / L2 norm of the vector is at least 1000.

With the example of the vector with (1,1,1): it increases to (512, 512, 512), where the l2 norm is about 886. This is less than 1000, so it gets multiplied by 2 again and becomes (1024, 1024, 1024). This has a magnitude greater than 1000, so it stops.

Answer (score 2):

### Lets break it step wise to understand the code better.

---

The below block of code creates a tensor **x** of shape (1,3)

```
x = torch.ones(3, requires_grad=True)
print(x)

>>> tensor([1., 1., 1.], requires_grad=True)
```

---

The below block of code creates a tensor **y** by multiplying each element of **x** by 2

```
y = x * 2
print(y)
print(y.requires_grad)

>>> tensor([2., 2., 2.], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
>>> True
```

---

TORCH.data returns a tensor whose **requires_grad** is set to false

```
print(y.data)
print('Type of y: ', type(y.data))
print('requires_grad: ', y.data.requires_grad)

>>> tensor([2., 2., 2.])
>>> Type of y:  <class 'torch.Tensor'>
>>> requires_grad:  False
```

---

TORCH.norm() Returns the matrix norm or vector norm of a given tensor. By default it returns a **Frobenius norm** aka **L2-Norm** which is calculated using the formula  
[image].

In our example since every element in **y** is **2**, y.data.norm() returns **3.4641** since [image] is equal to **3.4641**

```
print(y.data.norm())

>>> tensor(3.4641)
```

The below loop is run until the norm value is less than 1000

```
while y.data.norm() < 1000:
    print('Norm value: ', y.data.norm(), 'y value: ', y.data )
    y = y * 2

>>> Norm value:  tensor(6.9282) y value:  tensor([4., 4., 4.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(3.4641) y value:  tensor([2., 2., 2.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(13.8564) y value:  tensor([8., 8., 8.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(27.7128) y value:  tensor([16., 16., 16.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(55.4256) y value:  tensor([32., 32., 32.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(110.8512) y value:  tensor([64., 64., 64.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(221.7025) y value:  tensor([128., 128., 128.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(443.4050) y value:  tensor([256., 256., 256.])
>>> Norm value:  tensor(886.8100) y value:  tensor([512., 512., 512.])
>>> 
>>> Final y value:  tensor([1024., 1024., 1024.], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y.data.norm()
```

is equivalent to

```
torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(y, 2)))
```

Comment: elaborate more on your answer.